# Modify pseudo-element :after's width using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Markup:

```
<h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #aaa;
  position: relative;
}
.title:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HDBqe

I wanted to change the `.title:after`'s width based on the text's width, how do I change `:after`'s width using javascript?

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var html_org = $(this).html();
  var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
  $(this).html(html_calc);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html_org);
  return width;
};

$('.title').each(function(){
  // Change :after's width based on the text's width
  // .css('width', $(this).textWidth());
});
```

Comment: You can't access this pseudo-selector using JS.

Comment: He can change the style in the stylesheet

Comment: @Itay, that would be the approach that I'd take. Since pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM, you will have to target the stylesheet. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5041526/268093).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pseudo-element is not part of the DOM. Therefore, you cannot change its CSS properties directly through JS.

In order to get your desired effect the way *you* want it, my best guess would be [YUI.StyleSheet](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/stylesheet/) and manipulate the stylesheet itself, although I have to admit I haven't tested it myself in recent years.

Including such a utility and doing all of this calculation seems like a lot of work for width matching.

If you are willing to compromise a little bit on the semantic HTML, there is a working technique:

Your element takes the entire width of the screen. Wrapping the text with a span and adding the pseudo-element to that, as an `inline-block` should allow you to get the border under the text only

HTML:

```
<h1 class="title"><span>Hello World</span></h1>
```

CSS:

```css
.title {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #aaa;
    position: relative;
}

.title span{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

.title span:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here is [my version of the codePen](http://codepen.io/MasterAM/details/ilhub).

### For future reference:

There is a [W3C Candidate Recommendation](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#attr) that suggests the capability of using attributes for CSS properties other than `content`.

This way, if and when the recommendation is approved and implemented, it might be possible to have the pseudo-element reflect the parent's attributes, as such:

```
this.setAttribute("length", $(this).textWidth());
```

And the relevant CSS:

```css
.title:after {
    ...
    width: attr(length px);
    ...
}
```

Comment: how did you know you should be using `display:block`? My first thought was [`bottom: -3px; left: 0`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mFxiE) but the `display:block` trick worked.

Comment: FYI As of Chrome 59 this is still not supported :(

Comment: I don't know where you've got "width: attr(length px);" from but that doesn't work at all

Comment: As stated in this (fairly old) answer, this is a __candidate recommendation__, so there was no guarantee that it would ever be accepted. That said, having an attribute prefixed with `data-` might work.

Answer (score 18):

I've found a trick which works in this case. I've updated your demo:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bHLtk

```css
.title {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #aaa;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.title:after {
  content: "";
  width: inherit;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Notice, that `.title:after` has width set to `inherit` but his parent (`.title`) has overridden `width` with `min-width`. Now I can freely to set width by JavaScript to title and it take effect only on his nested pseudoelement:

```js
$('.title').each(function(){
  $(this).css('width', $(this).textWidth());
});
```

Comment: Great job thinking outside the div.

Comment: This is very clever, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How's this for a different approach.... http://jsfiddle.net/mayYt/

### Added CSS

```
.title span {
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

### JQuery

```
$('.title').wrapInner('<span />');
```

Answer (score 0):

With just a simple trick any pseudo-element can be changed (or at least replaced with something else):

```js
$('.something').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('to_show');
});
```

```css
.something
{
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
.something.to_show:after
{
  content: "X";
  color: white;
  background: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.something:after
{
  content: "O";
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="something">
      click here!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```